# Nautilus's 'open with' list

Tags: nautilus, plasma

In nautilus when I try to open a pdf with Adobe Reader, I cannot find Adobe Reader in `open with...`. In dolphin there's not such problem.

How can I add Adobe Reader Link to "Open With..." list in nautilus?

I use nautilus in KDE environment.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand/68023#68023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the installed program have a  `.desktop` that have to be edited to be listed in nautilus's "open with list"
to do that,you first have to locate that file

```
ls /usr/share/applications/`
```

you should be able to guess the `.desktop` associated with your program.
let's say i want to add vlc to the list, i edit the desktop file with

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
```

and change `Exec=vlc` to `Exec=vlc %u`

in your case you edit:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/AdobeReader.desktop
```

and change `Exec=AdobeReader` to `Exec=AdobeReader %u`

Comment: Just a note %u and %U behave differently in case of multiple file selection...  from Nautilus actions documentation:  
"singular" one, e.g. "%b", the basename of the selected item,

"plural" one, e.g. "%B", a space-separated list of the basenames of selected items

Answer (score 1):

Use `mimeopen` to select the default option. The application will be available in Nautilus also.

From [`man mimeopen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mimeopen.1p.html)

```
-d, --ask-default
       Let the user choose a new default program for given files.
```

Just run in terminal

```
 mimeopen -d file.pdf
```

and choose your option. It will be default from Nautilus also.

**Example:**

```
souravc@vworkstation:~/Downloads$ mimeopen -d asgmnt.pdf 
Please choose a default application for files of type application/pdf

1) Document Viewer  (evince)
2) Adobe Reader 9  (AdobeReader)
3) Other...

use application #2
Opening "asgmnt.pdf" with Adobe Reader 9  (application/pdf)
```