# How to link specific file type with some applications?

Tags: nautilus

I need tecplot360 to open .plt files, and after I install it on my  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the software didn't show in the 'open with' lists, After I add 'Tec 360' to 'open with' lists(according to [Nautilus's 'open with' list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445373/nautiluss-open-with-list)), I find all my text files (such as .txt, .dat etc) would automatically open with tecplot360. 
I just want tecplot360 only link with .plt files, how?
Thanks.

Comment: It probably thinks that the file is a text file, so opens all text files in tecplot360. If you [create a mimetype for the file](http://askubuntu.com/q/478029/178596) (replacing 'foobar' with tecplot360-file, and `.foo` with '.plt', or something like that), you should be able to set tecplot as the default app to open those files.

Comment: @Wilf Thanks a lot. And I also linked other files like '.lay' and '.lpk' with Tecplot by creating different 'application-tec360-XX.xml' files. :)